# HashMap not functioning as expected

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have made a 3 x 3 box matrix. 
Clicking on either one of the box adds the element to the hashmap
Eg , click on 1st box adds "imageView1" as a key and "true" as a value to the hashmap.

There are two players , hence two hashmaps player1 and player2.

```
player1.put("imageView1","true");
```

So when either of the player clicks on the box , the respective box name is added to the respective hashmap.

Then to check if the player has won

```
  if(player1.containsKey("imageView1") 
     &&player1.containsKey("imageView2")
     &&player1.containsKey("imageView3")){
        return true;
    }
```

But this doesnt work . Can you help me with it?
Note: I didnt put the whole algorithm .. I just checked 1 condition (ie. if 1 2 3 are checked then player 1 won, like tic tac toe

Heres are the files

MainActivity.java(original) (http://pastebin.com/AtypDtuC)

MainActivity.java(condensed) (http://pastebin.com/gJCud9WE)

Content_Main.xml (http://pastebin.com/vsWd0Jii)

Comment: Please read this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PaulBoddington Thankyou for pointing that out . I made a new project and made a condensed version , removing the default and unedited lines of codes(except the import statements) .

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine but I would suggest inspecting what

```
getResources().getResourceName(view.getId())
```

is putting inside your map. Specifically you should confirm that:

```
getResources().getResourceName(view.getId()).equals("imageView1")
getResources().getResourceName(view.getId()).equals("imageView2")
getResources().getResourceName(view.getId()).equals("imageView3")
getResources().getResourceName(view.getId()).equals("imageView4")
...
getResources().getResourceName(view.getId()).equals("imageViewN")
```

is true at least once. I.e. you need to ensure that you are putting in `Strings` which are exactly the same as when you call `.contains()`, otherwise you will never get a match with `.contains()`

Comment: Hello,
I tried that extract with "&&" in an online java compiler and it return "true" wheen imageView1 to imageView 3 with an exach hashmap and i took the values by Log.i("Value",""+getResources().getResourceName(view.getId()) ) ;

for creating the hashmap key pair .. and then executed it. And its working properly...